# java.time.Year#range does not return a concrete week of year (Java 1.8)

Tags: java, java-time

I'm wondering why a concrete instance of `java.time.Year#range` fails to return a concrete `ValueRange` of possible week numbers.

---

I know that the following code fails, because `IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR` is not supported:

```
ValueRange range = Year.of(2018).range(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR)
```

Nevertheless, I am wondering why the following code returns a `ValueRange` of `0/1 - 52/54`:

```
ValueRange range = Year.of(2018).range(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear())
```

I know that this is true, but it is a generic `ValueRange` true of any `Year`.

---

From what I gather, given a concrete instance of a year, you are able to find out the actual range of numbers of weeks that fit into this particular year (in this example `Year.of(2018)` contains weeks `1 - 52` (since 2018-12-31 actually belongs to `2019-W01`.

Same rant basically applies to YearMonth.

---

The only way I know to get the proper range is with the following:

```
LocalDate date = Year.of(2021).atDay(4)
ValueRange range2 = date.range(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()) // 1-52
```

since --01-04 is the one that always belongs to --W01, so you have to beware that the following will actually yield different result:

```
LocalDate date = Year.of(2021).atDay(1)
ValueRange range = date.range(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()) // 1-53 (incorrect!)
```

Still, it seems somehow wrong to create some arbitrary date just for the reason of getting the value range of possible week numbers in a given year.

---

So, basically, what I would like to ask is what is the reason for this and if you know any better ways to do this?

Also, I haven't had a change to try this in Java versions other than 1.8; perhaps this was improved in JDK9/10/11?

Comment: I’m surprised to learn that `WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()` counts as a supported field at all. After all a year doesn’t have a week field.

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn’t this generally so? Neither `Month.MARCH` nor a `YearMonth` of March 2019 will tell me the range of day of month. I need to “invent” an arbitrary date in the month in question. A `LocalDate` will give me a range of day of month (I don’t know why a `MonthDay` won’t).

Comment: Java 11 has the same behavior, for what it’s worth.

Comment: Yeah, after some further thinking, I came to the conclusion that you can not in fact offer a value range for week numbers in a Year.  You can do that for any [week-based-year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). But a year can (and in fact always does) overlap with multiple week-based-years.

Following an earlier example – 2021 will contain both 2020W53, 2021W01 and 2021W52.
So, saying that it contains weeks with numbers in range of 1-52 or 1-53 is untrue; and so it is for any other year / value range.